# Prevent mat-select to trigger mouseleave event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 `mat-card` components which contains a `mat-select` each. I track the mouse on which `mat-card` it currently is. Therefore I use 2 events:

- mouseenter - when the mouse is on the mat-card
- mouseleave - when it leaves the card

Those events triggers methods that will update the selected mat-card.

HTML:

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="50px">

  <mat-card (mouseenter)="select('0')" (mouseleave)="unselectCards()">
    <h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card (mouseenter)="select('1')" (mouseleave)="unselectCards()">
    <h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-card>

  <span>Selected: {{ selectedCard }}</span>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  selectedCard = '1';

  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  select(card: string) {
    this.selectedCard = card;
  }

  unselectCards() {
    this.selectedCard = '';
  }
}
```

The key issue here is when I open the `mat-select` to select an option. This will trigger the `mouseleave` event which is **not intended**. Do you know how to prevent the triggering of the `mouseleave` event?

Short facts:

- `selectedCard` holds the value of the current card location of the mouse
- (mouseenter) selects the card
- (mouseleave) sets the value to an empty string
- `mat-select` triggers the (mouseleave) event what I don't want. It should stay on the same value as before. How can I solve this.

Thank you so far.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48t5yk

Comment: Updated the demo link

Comment: what do you want to do here exactly?

Comment: I want to stay on the selected card while operating some form elements without losing focus, but currently I lose focus when I just touch the mat-select element

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can check if the `mat-select` is open or not like this and update the selection when the `mat-select` toggles:

```
<mat-card (mouseenter)="select('1')" (mouseleave)="!matSelect.panelOpen && unselectCards()">
  <h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select #matSelect="matSelect" (openedChange)="$event ? select('1') : unselectCards()">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-card>
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48t5yk-ucjd6j?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Comment: I think it is not the best way how to do it, because I need to stack this on every similar form element, but I'll keep this as last way. Thanks

Comment: @LingVu if you have to do this more than once, it will be best to make some kind of directive which will handle this for you. However you would still need to pass the reference of the form element causing it

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Solved it by checking the target of the MouseEvent.

**component.html**

```
<div (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)">your component</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
onMouseLeave(event: MouseEvent): void {
  if ((event.relatedTarget as HTMLInputElement).className !== 'mat-option-text') {
    // your action on leave
  }
}
```